# "Template rules match elements in no namespace" message

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I realize namespace questions are a dime a dozen, but I am getting from Saxon:

> Warning   SXXP0005: The source document is in namespace
>   http://docbook.org/ns/docbook, b ut all the   template rules match
>   elements in no namespace (Use --suppressXsltNamespaceChec k:on to
>   avoid this warning)

The root element of my source file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <topic xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
    xml:id="103829">
    <info>
        <title>My title</title>
    </info>
    <procedure>
...
```

And my XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">

<!-- Dummy template, just trying to match anything -->      
    <xsl:template match="procedure">
        <orderedlist>
            SOME TEXT
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </orderedlist>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As warned, the template does not match. But I do not know why: I thought that having the same default namespace in the source file and XSL file prevented this sort of errors.

Also, I suppose I could declare a prefix and apply it to all elements. But was not avoiding prefixes the whole point of default namespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (XSLT 2 and later) `xpath-default-namespace="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` if you want your pattern and expressions like `procedure` to match/select elements in that namespace. Otherwise `procedure` matches/selects elements of that name in no namespace.

An `xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` in the stylesheet only serves to put the result elements (like the `orderedlist` in your sample) into that namespace.